# Why is "pamdepth" not in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, image-processing

The tool [pamdepth](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pamdepth.html) is much better than the tool `pnmdepth`.

I could not find a reason why it is not included in Ubuntu 16.04.

Why is "pamdepth" not in Ubuntu 16.04?

```
root@host> apt install netpbm
...
netpbm is already the newest version (2:10.0-15.3).
```

OK, netpbm is already installed.

```
  dpkg -L netpbm| grep pamdepth --> no output, not installed
```

Comment: Seems like a bug you want to report…

Comment: Please see my edited answer for a solution.

Comment: @MarkKirby again, the question: Why is "pamdepth” not in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I answered that, it is not in the Debian build but it is in the source forge build. To find out exactly why, you NEED to ask the devs (or Debian as maintainers). If that is all you want to know and don't care about getting it working, then this is off topic, we are not the devs, we do not know the details, contact them and make a request.

Answer (score 3):

The package `pamdepth` is in the packge `netpbm`, however, the version in the repository does not seem to contain `pamdepth`, here is how I got it to work

The two versions conflict so

```
sudo apt purge netpbm
```

Download

```
wget downloads.sourceforge.net/project/netpbm/super_stable/10.47.62/netpbm-sf-10.47.62_amd64.deb?r=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fnetpbm%2F%3Fsource%3Dtyp_redirect&ts=1472465698&use_mirror=freefr
```

or [download here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/netpbm/?source=typ_redirect), now it had dependencies I could not resolve via apt (IDK why), so I installed it via `software` or double click the deb.

That was it, it is working, here is proof
[image]

Comment: Lol. I like these types of answers

Comment: @Anwar We all love an easy one :)

Comment: I updated the question. I installed netbpm and it is still missing.

Comment: Hmmm, hang on I am looking in to it.

Comment: Seems like the Debian package is out of date (10.0) compared to the latest version (10.47.62) here you can find a .deb for the latest version https://sourceforge.net/projects/netpbm/files/super_stable/10.47.62/ install it over the old version and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Actually, Debian/Ubuntu has a fork (for licensing reasons, if I understand correctly) and the version numbers aren't really comparable (supposedly 10.0 is a mixture of upstream 10.x parts). Using the upstream version might still solve @guettli's problem.

Comment: @JanC I can confirm it did fix the issue :)]

Comment: What I mean by “might” is that some utilities in upstream `netpbm` _might_ work slightly different from those in Debian/Ubuntu because of version/fork differences, which _might_ require some testing.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

1. sudo apt remove netpbm
2. wget -O netpbm-sf-10.73.33_amd64.deb https://sourceforge.net/projects/netpbm/files/super_stable/10.73.33/netpbm-sf-10.73.33_amd64.deb/download
3. sudo apt install libpng16-16
4. sudo dpkg -i ./netpbm-sf-10.73.33_amd64.deb
5. sudo chown -R root.root /usr/share/netpbm
6. sudo chmod -R ugo+rX /usr/share/netpbm

**BACKGROUND**

Debian (and hence Ubuntu), for licensing reasons, uses an old copy of netpbm with stuff removed. From the netpbm website:

http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/getting_netpbm.php

> If you use Debian or Ubuntu, note that their Netpbm package is
> essentially Netpbm 9.25 from 2002, minus a bunch of unimportant
> programs. Also note that the Debian version numbering is not
> consistent with Sourceforge Netpbm, so a program may appear to be from
> e.g. Sourceforge Netpbm 10.0, but is actually 9.25. In 2002, Debian
> decided for various reasons not to distribute regular Netpbm and
> instead created its own variation of it. That variation was too hard
> to update with ongoing development on the main branch of Netpbm, so no
> one has done so. Ubuntu is based on Debian. There is a Debian bug
> report and a Ubuntu bug report about this. The Debian bug report was
> opened in 2006 and something updating the Debian package to current
> Sourceforge Netpbm was uploaded somewhere in June 2017; it will
> presumably be in Debian and Ubuntu releases soon. (The foregoing is so
> as of September 2017).
>
> The Netpbm source tree contains a program (mkdeb) that creates a
> Debian install package (.deb file) after you've built Netpbm form
> source, so you can easily add modern Netpbm to your system. (This was
> new in Netpbm 10.66 - March 2014).
>
> Furthermore, the Netpbm project distributes a complete Debian install
> package (.deb file) for the x86_64 architecture for the current Super
> Stable release, and it appears to be compatible with Debian 6
> (Squeeze) and 7 (Wheezy). It remains to be seen how well this package
> works with actual Debian systems; the facts that the package is not
> maintained by the Debian project and the Debian project does maintain
> another version of the package are reasons to be skeptical. The Netpbm
> project has distributed this package since March 2014.
>
> You can find the Debian install package in the Sourceforge File
> Release System

Funny that they would say "unimportant programs" as these are the very ones that people want (e.g. pamdepth, pamcomp, pnmrotate, etc)!

Comment: Incidentally, for the same licensing reasons, macOS also has a lot of very old packages (e.g bash). That's why many use The MacPorts Project to get the latest versions on that platform. FOSS is great but the licensing is a dog's breakfast.